# How to open specific web page in ASP.net that I'm working on or find pages that referring it in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've edited an ascx.cs page which I thought was relevant. When I ran the service to debug that code it wasn't the right place - The breakpoint didn't stop the service.

I know how to find the right page to edit but now I want to see what did I edit.

How can I open the page or find which pages are referring to it so I could check it also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you "set as startup" that project already ? then try setting that page aspx.cs as "startup page".

After setting above both , your project will start that same projects same page that you have set up as startup.

Alternatively you can type link to that manually in address bar to get there.

Comment: Thank you. Now I've noticed that it's ascx and not aspx. It don't let me to set it as startup page, I'll keep searching now.

Comment: what about trying the manual link of ascx through address bar ?

Answer (score 0):

While trying to set it as startup page I've found out it ascx and not aspx file. So if You want I wanted to see the edits I would need to load that page as asp controller.